# How to customize the window frame of my flutter desktop application

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, flutter-desktop

working on flutter desktop application and I want to customize my application window's look like hide title bar. I am using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window to do so but when I run my application it gives this error message[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyehR.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyehR.png). Can anyone tell me please what is the issues and how can be resolved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried re-running the app?

Comment: Yes, I did but still same even after flutter clean